# Node native module - linking a static library

Tags: c++, node.js, boost

I'm building a NodeJS native module which has a dependency on another library (libboost-regex).

If I dynamically link the library using the below binding.gyp file everything works:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "libraries": [
          "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so",
          "-ludev"
      ],
      "target_name": "utils",
      "sources": [ "src/native/utils.cpp" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However this way it works only on my machine. On another Linux machine it says this module libboost_regex.so is not found.
And on some Linux distros this version (currently 1.58) is not even available.

Is it possible to staticly link it, so it gets included into my output module?

I read a post here that I only need to change the .so version to .a version which is the static library:
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/328#issuecomment-24335081

However if I replace it with this:
"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.a"

I now get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.a(instances.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
utils.target.mk:125: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/utils.node' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/utils.node] Error 1
```

The above error also appears if I add -static to the linker options.

Another attempt:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "libraries": [
          "-ludev", "-lboost_regex"
      ],
      "target_name": "utils",
      "cflags!": ["-fPIC"],
      "ldflags" : [ "-Wl,-static" ],
      "sources": [ "src/native/utils.cpp" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Leads to a similar error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: Release/obj.target/utils/src/native/utils.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
Release/obj.target/utils/src/native/utils.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
utils.target.mk:123: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/utils.node' failed
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, `.a` files are archives of `.o` files compiled without `-fPIC` flag. Whereas code for shared libraries must be compiled with `-fPIC`. This is why you cannot link your shared library with `libboost_regex.a`.

Boost static libraries need to be recompiled with `-fPIC` flag, so that `.a` files can be linked into position-independent shared libraries. With boost `b2` build tool it is `cxxflags='-fPIC'` command line option.

Alternatively, you can build boost with shared libraries only and then link your shared libraries against individual `.o` files used to link boost shared libraries.

Comment: That worked, I recompiled boost with -fPIC and can now successfully link the .a module. Thanks so much!